# My java program only prompts the user but does not read the data. How can I make my code actually read the data and perform the calculations?

Tags: java

My program is supposed to ask the user if they would like to order a pizza and the user is supposed to enter

`yes or no` (all lower case)

Entering no will exit the program but entering yes will then make the computer prompt the user again for this information-

`Last name` (one word, no need to validate)

`Choice of pizza type` (options are veggie, cheese, pepperoni, and supreme)

`Choice of pizza size` (options are small, medium, and large)

Once you have entered all of this information the program is supposed to print the following information

`customer last name` (whatever was entered in)

`cost of pizza`

`total number of large pizzas`

`total number of medium pizzas`

`total number of small pizzas`

`average cost of an order`

When I compiled my program there were no errors and when I ran it I was prompted perfectly...However, after you type in your answers the program simply starts over again and prompts from the beginning. It does not output anything or do any calculations. It doesn't even check if what you enter is correct. I'm not sure where I went wrong? Was it my logic, my code, or both? Can someone please show me how to fix this. Thank you!

Oh, and I used Notepad++ and compiled and ran it in the command prompt if this is helpful information.

```
    /*This program will keep prompting the user to enter their pizza order, perform 
  the requested calculation, and then output the requested result.
  Written by Hannah Lane*/

import java.util.Scanner;
public class PizzaOrders
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int smallpizzas = 0, mediumpizzas = 0, largepizzas = 0, numberoforders = 0;
    double totalordercost = 0.0, pizzacost = 0.0, averagecost = 0.0;
    String custlastname = "", pizzasize = "", pizzatype ="", response = "";

    /*The loop will prompt the user to see if the customer would like to order a pizza. 
      If yes, it will prompt the user for their last name, choice of pizza type, and 
      their choice of pizza size. The two possible responses are yes and no. The dummy 
      value for the loop is no. */

      System.out.print("Do you want to order one pizza?" +
             "Type yes or no (all lower case), then press the ENTER key.");
             response = input.next();
             while (!(response.equals("no")))
             {
                /*Validate the user's response. If it is valid, prompt for the required 
                  values, perform the calculation, and output the result. If invalid, 
                  output an error message. */

                if (response.equals("yes"))
                {
                  System.out.println("Please type in your last name (it can only be one word) and then press the ENTER key.");
                  custlastname = input.next();
                  System.out.println("Please type in your choice of pizza in all lower case letters. What you type into the keyboard must be" +
                                     " pepperoni, veggie, cheese, or supreme.");
                  pizzatype = input.next();
                  System.out.println("Please type in your choice of pizza size in all lower case letters. What you type into the keyboard must" +
                                     " be small, medium, or large.");

                  pizzasize = input.next();

                  /* Validate the entries for the calculation. The sizes must be small, medium, or large. The types of
                     pizza must be pepperoni, veggie, cheese, or supreme. For division, we must make sure the denominator
                     is not zero. If invalid, output an error message. */

                  if (pizzatype.equals("pepperoni") || pizzatype.equals("veggie") || pizzatype.equals("cheese") ||
                      pizzatype.equals("supreme") && pizzasize.equals("small") || pizzasize.equals("medium") ||
                      pizzasize.equals("large") && numberoforders !=0.0) 
                    {
                       if (pizzatype.equals ("pepperoni"))
                       {
                           if (pizzasize.equals ("small"))
                           {
                             smallpizzas = smallpizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 8.50;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 8.50;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                           else if (pizzasize.equals ("medium"))
                           {
                             mediumpizzas = mediumpizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 9.50;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 9.50;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                            else if(pizzasize.equals ("large"))
                            {
                             largepizzas = largepizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 10.50;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 10.50;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (pizzatype.equals ("veggie"))
                        {
                          if (pizzasize.equals ("small"))
                          {
                            smallpizzas = smallpizzas + 1;
                            pizzacost = 10.00;
                            totalordercost = totalordercost + 10.00;
                            numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                           }
                           else if (pizzasize.equals ("medium"))
                           {
                             mediumpizzas = mediumpizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 12.25;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 12.25;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                            else if (pizzasize.equals ("large"))
                            {
                             largepizzas = largepizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 14.50;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 14.50;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;   
                            }
                        }
                        else if (pizzatype.equals ("cheese"))
                        {
                          if (pizzasize.equals ("small"))
                          {
                            smallpizzas = smallpizzas + 1;
                            pizzacost = 7.00;
                            totalordercost = totalordercost + 7.00;
                            numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                           }
                            else if (pizzasize.equals ("medium"))
                           {
                             mediumpizzas = mediumpizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 8.00;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 8.00;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                            else if (pizzasize.equals ("large"))
                            {
                             largepizzas = largepizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 9.00;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 9.00;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (pizzatype.equals ("supreme"))
                        {
                          if (pizzasize.equals ("small"))
                          {
                            smallpizzas = smallpizzas + 1;
                            pizzacost = 11.00;
                            totalordercost = totalordercost + 11.00;
                            numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                           }
                           else if (pizzasize.equals ("medium"))
                           {
                             mediumpizzas = mediumpizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 14.00;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 14.00;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                            else if (pizzasize.equals ("large"))
                            {
                             largepizzas = largepizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 16.00;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 16.00;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                          averagecost = totalordercost/(double)numberoforders;
                          System.out.println(custlastname + pizzacost + smallpizzas + mediumpizzas + largepizzas + averagecost);
                        }
                    }
                }
                  else
                      System.out.println("What you have typed in is incorrect. Your response must be yes or no.");

                  System.out.println("Do you want to order one pizza? Type yes or no" +
                          "(all lower case), then press the ENTER key.");
                  response = input.next();
            }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code to print out the order will only be executed in case the user is buying a supreme small pizza. Check the location of the print line it's within the if-else structure. You should move it a bit lower (just before the last else). Check the code below, I moved the following line around:

```
System.out.println(custlastname + pizzacost + smallpizzas + mediumpizzas + largepizzas + averagecost);
```

Complete code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PizzaOrders
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int smallpizzas = 0, mediumpizzas = 0, largepizzas = 0, numberoforders = 0;
    double totalordercost = 0.0, pizzacost = 0.0, averagecost = 0.0;
    String custlastname = "", pizzasize = "", pizzatype ="", response = "";

    /*The loop will prompt the user to see if the customer would like to order a pizza. 
      If yes, it will prompt the user for their last name, choice of pizza type, and 
      their choice of pizza size. The two possible responses are yes and no. The dummy 
      value for the loop is no. */

      System.out.print("Do you want to order one pizza?" +
             "Type yes or no (all lower case), then press the ENTER key.");
             response = input.next();
             while (!(response.equals("no")))
             {
                /*Validate the user's response. If it is valid, prompt for the required 
                  values, perform the calculation, and output the result. If invalid, 
                  output an error message. */

                if (response.equals("yes"))
                {
                  System.out.println("Please type in your last name (it can only be one word) and then press the ENTER key.");
                  custlastname = input.next();
                  System.out.println("Please type in your choice of pizza in all lower case letters. What you type into the keyboard must be" +
                                     " pepperoni, veggie, cheese, or supreme.");
                  pizzatype = input.next();
                  System.out.println("Please type in your choice of pizza size in all lower case letters. What you type into the keyboard must" +
                                     " be small, medium, or large.");

                  pizzasize = input.next();

                  /* Validate the entries for the calculation. The sizes must be small, medium, or large. The types of
                     pizza must be pepperoni, veggie, cheese, or supreme. For division, we must make sure the denominator
                     is not zero. If invalid, output an error message. */

                  if (pizzatype.equals("pepperoni") || pizzatype.equals("veggie") || pizzatype.equals("cheese") ||
                      pizzatype.equals("supreme") && pizzasize.equals("small") || pizzasize.equals("medium") ||
                      pizzasize.equals("large") && numberoforders !=0.0) 
                    {
                       if (pizzatype.equals ("pepperoni"))
                       {
                           if (pizzasize.equals ("small"))
                           {
                             smallpizzas = smallpizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 8.50;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 8.50;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                           else if (pizzasize.equals ("medium"))
                           {
                             mediumpizzas = mediumpizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 9.50;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 9.50;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                            else if(pizzasize.equals ("large"))
                            {
                             largepizzas = largepizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 10.50;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 10.50;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (pizzatype.equals ("veggie"))
                        {
                          if (pizzasize.equals ("small"))
                          {
                            smallpizzas = smallpizzas + 1;
                            pizzacost = 10.00;
                            totalordercost = totalordercost + 10.00;
                            numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                           }
                           else if (pizzasize.equals ("medium"))
                           {
                             mediumpizzas = mediumpizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 12.25;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 12.25;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                            else if (pizzasize.equals ("large"))
                            {
                             largepizzas = largepizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 14.50;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 14.50;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;   
                            }
                        }
                        else if (pizzatype.equals ("cheese"))
                        {
                          if (pizzasize.equals ("small"))
                          {
                            smallpizzas = smallpizzas + 1;
                            pizzacost = 7.00;
                            totalordercost = totalordercost + 7.00;
                            numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                           }
                            else if (pizzasize.equals ("medium"))
                           {
                             mediumpizzas = mediumpizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 8.00;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 8.00;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                            else if (pizzasize.equals ("large"))
                            {
                             largepizzas = largepizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 9.00;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 9.00;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (pizzatype.equals ("supreme"))
                        {
                          if (pizzasize.equals ("small"))
                          {
                            smallpizzas = smallpizzas + 1;
                            pizzacost = 11.00;
                            totalordercost = totalordercost + 11.00;
                            numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                           }
                           else if (pizzasize.equals ("medium"))
                           {
                             mediumpizzas = mediumpizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 14.00;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 14.00;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                            else if (pizzasize.equals ("large"))
                            {
                             largepizzas = largepizzas + 1;
                             pizzacost = 16.00;
                             totalordercost = totalordercost + 16.00;
                             numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
                            }
                          averagecost = totalordercost/(double)numberoforders;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(custlastname + pizzacost + smallpizzas + mediumpizzas + largepizzas + averagecost);
                }
                  else
                      System.out.println("What you have typed in is incorrect. Your response must be yes or no.");

                  System.out.println("Do you want to order one pizza? Type yes or no" +
                          "(all lower case), then press the ENTER key.");
                  response = input.next();
            }

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, it still isn't doing anything but prompting. It seems that there's something wrong with my code, like I didn't properly tell it to calculate. I'm just not sure how to fix it or where the problem is exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Must place the System.out.println() just before else condition

```
averagecost = totalordercost/(double)numberoforders;
    //Remove this line====> System.out.println(custlastname + pizzacost + smallpizzas + mediumpizzas + largepizzas + averagecost); <=== remove this
                    }
                }
/*Add it here */ System.out.println(custlastname + pizzacost + smallpizzas + mediumpizzas + largepizzas + averagecost); //<== Add it here
            }
              else
                  System.out.println("What you have typed in is incorrect. Your response must be yes or no.");
```

Comment: I added your correction but my program continues to only prompt and do nothing else. I think somehow it isn't reading the calculation commands correctly. I'm just not sure how to fix it and where the problem is in the code exactly.

Comment: @Hannah I have tested ur code it is working fine with the changes

Comment: When I test my code with the changes it has me enter all of the information and then after I have entered the pizza size I want (I chose small) and hit enter it brings back the first question it asks me whether or not I would like to order a pizza. On my command prompt it doesn't show any printing of any kind. What are you using to run it?

Answer (score 0):

For your input-validation you need something like this:

```
boolean type = false;
 while (!type) {
                  System.out.println("Please type in your choice of pizza in all lower case letters. What you type into the keyboard must be" +
                          " pepperoni, veggie, cheese, or supreme.");
                  pizzatype = input.next();
                  if (pizzatype.equals("pepperoni") || pizzatype.equals("veggie") || pizzatype.equals("cheese") ||
                          pizzatype.equals("supreme")){
                      type = true;
                  }else{
                      System.out.println("What you have typed in is incorrect. Your response must be pepperoni, veggie, cheese, or supreme.");
                      type = false;
                  }
            }
type = false;
```

If the input is correct, you will continue else u will ask again and again untill the input is correct.

Maybe you can change the position of the last-name-question to a position before the "while (!(response.equals("no")))" loop. so I dont have to type it again if I want a second pizza.

Comment: Where would you put this exactly? I tried replacing my data validation with this but the program didn't seem to change. It still prompted me with no output.

Comment: @Hannah: Instead of  `System.out.println("Please type in your choice of pizza in all lower case letters. What you type into the keyboard must be" +
                                     " pepperoni, veggie, cheese, or supreme.");
                  pizzatype = input.next();` use this loop. Maybe you have a problem with saving or recompile your changes?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I put it in my code but in my command prompt, when I run it, the program still prompts me without outputting anything. I wonder if somehow the calculations in my code aren't being read in?

Comment: I've got your mistake :) You have to place the calculation of `averagecost = totalordercost/numberoforders;` one line down after the closing } of the `else if (pizzatype.equals ("supreme"))`. After this it will calculate correctly. But why dont you want to see the total cost?

Comment: For some reason even when I move it one line down my command prompt still shows that there are no calculations being done when I run it...:/ Haha the reason for no total cost is simply because the assignment does not call for it.

Comment: It looks like that: `}
     }
     averagecost = totalordercost / (double) numberoforders;
    }
    System.out.println(custlastname + " " + pizzacost + " " + smallpizzas
      + " " + mediumpizzas  + " " + largepizzas + " " + averagecost + " "
      + totalordercost);` I've got the output: "a 12.25 0 1 0 12.25 12.25". maybe you can use [eclipse](https://eclipse.org/home/index.php) to debug and run your programm? It's way more comfortable than notepad++ ;-)

Comment: I just might try eclipse because I'm still not seeing the outcome on my command prompt. Oh well, thanks for all your help! I'll see if I can try to get this working a little later.

Answer (score 0):

Here my optimized complete working code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int smallpizzas = 0, mediumpizzas = 0, largepizzas = 0, numberoforders = 0;
    double totalordercost = 0.0, pizzacost = 0.0, averagecost = 0.0;
    String custlastname = "", pizzasize = "", pizzatype = "", response = "";
    boolean type = false;
    boolean size = false;
    /*
     * The loop will prompt the user to see if the customer would like to
     * order a pizza. If yes, it will prompt the user for their last name,
     * choice of pizza type, and their choice of pizza size. The two
     * possible responses are yes and no. The dummy value for the loop is
     * no.
     */

    System.out.print("Do you want to order one pizza?"
            + "Type yes or no (all lower case), then press the ENTER key.");
    response = input.next();
    while (!(response.equals("no"))) {
        /*
         * Validate the user's response. If it is valid, prompt for the
         * required values, perform the calculation, and output the result.
         * If invalid, output an error message.
         */

        if (response.equals("yes")) {
            if (custlastname.isEmpty()) {
                System.out
                        .println("Please type in your last name (it can only be one word) and then press the ENTER key.");
                custlastname = input.next();
            }
            while (!type) {
                System.out
                        .println("Please type in your choice of pizza in all lower case letters. What you type into the keyboard must be"
                                + " pepperoni, veggie, cheese, or supreme.");
                pizzatype = input.next();
                if (pizzatype.equals("pepperoni")
                        || pizzatype.equals("veggie")
                        || pizzatype.equals("cheese")
                        || pizzatype.equals("supreme")) {
                    type = true;
                } else {
                    System.out
                            .println("What you have typed in is incorrect. Your response must be pepperoni, veggie, cheese, or supreme.");
                    type = false;
                }
            }
            type = false;
            while (!size) {
                System.out
                        .println("Please type in your choice of pizza size in all lower case letters. What you type into the keyboard must"
                                + " be small, medium, or large.");

                pizzasize = input.next();
                if (pizzasize.equals("small") || pizzasize.equals("medium")
                        || pizzasize.equals("large")) {
                    size = true;
                } else {
                    System.out
                            .println("What you have typed in is incorrect. Your response must be small, medium, or large.");
                    size = false;
                }
            }
            size = false;

            /*
             * Validate the entries for the calculation. The sizes must be
             * small, medium, or large. The types of pizza must be
             * pepperoni, veggie, cheese, or supreme. For division, we must
             * make sure the denominator is not zero. If invalid, output an
             * error message.
             */

            if (pizzatype.equals("pepperoni")) {
                if (pizzasize.equals("small")) {
                    smallpizzas = smallpizzas + 1;
                    pizzacost = 8.50;
                    totalordercost = totalordercost + 8.50;
                } else if (pizzasize.equals("medium")) {
                    mediumpizzas = mediumpizzas + 1;
                    pizzacost = 9.50;
                    totalordercost = totalordercost + 9.50;
                } else if (pizzasize.equals("large")) {
                    largepizzas = largepizzas + 1;
                    pizzacost = 10.50;
                    totalordercost = totalordercost + 10.50;
                }
                numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
            } else if (pizzatype.equals("veggie")) {
                if (pizzasize.equals("small")) {
                    smallpizzas = smallpizzas + 1;
                    pizzacost = 10.00;
                    totalordercost = totalordercost + 10.00;
                } else if (pizzasize.equals("medium")) {
                    mediumpizzas = mediumpizzas + 1;
                    pizzacost = 12.25;
                    totalordercost = totalordercost + 12.25;
                } else if (pizzasize.equals("large")) {
                    largepizzas = largepizzas + 1;
                    pizzacost = 14.50;
                    totalordercost = totalordercost + 14.50;
                }
                numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
            } else if (pizzatype.equals("cheese")) {
                if (pizzasize.equals("small")) {
                    smallpizzas = smallpizzas + 1;
                    pizzacost = 7.00;
                    totalordercost = totalordercost + 7.00;
                } else if (pizzasize.equals("medium")) {
                    mediumpizzas = mediumpizzas + 1;
                    pizzacost = 8.00;
                    totalordercost = totalordercost + 8.00;
                } else if (pizzasize.equals("large")) {
                    largepizzas = largepizzas + 1;
                    pizzacost = 9.00;
                    totalordercost = totalordercost + 9.00;
                }
                numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
            } else if (pizzatype.equals("supreme")) {
                if (pizzasize.equals("small")) {
                    smallpizzas = smallpizzas + 1;
                    pizzacost = 11.00;
                    totalordercost = totalordercost + 11.00;
                } else if (pizzasize.equals("medium")) {
                    mediumpizzas = mediumpizzas + 1;
                    pizzacost = 14.00;
                    totalordercost = totalordercost + 14.00;
                } else if (pizzasize.equals("large")) {
                    largepizzas = largepizzas + 1;
                    pizzacost = 16.00;
                    totalordercost = totalordercost + 16.00;
                }
                numberoforders = numberoforders + 1;
            }
            averagecost = totalordercost / (double) numberoforders;
            System.out.println(custlastname + " " + pizzacost + " "
                    + smallpizzas + " " + mediumpizzas + " " + largepizzas
                    + " " + averagecost + " " + totalordercost);
        } else
            System.out
                    .println("What you have typed in is incorrect. Your response must be yes or no.");

        System.out.println("Do you want to order one pizza? Type yes or no"
                + "(all lower case), then press the ENTER key.");
        response = input.next();
    }

}
```

I hope this will help you understand your mistakes ;)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out.